# MySQL - SELECT INTO (SQL Error (1045): Access denied for user 'test'@'%' (using password: YES))

Tags: mysql, csv, select, select-into

When I try to export records using the below query, I am getting an error

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Emp 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/temp/hash.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Error:

> SQL Error (1045): Access denied for user 'test'@'%' (using password: YES)

I am getting same error while running the below:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'test';

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
secure_file_priv:  /tmp/
```

I want to run a stored procedure to export the records through a .Net application. I am expecting the output file to be created on the windows computer. The MySQL instance is running on AWS.I think the "secure_file_priv" path is causing the issue. The same query is working in another MySQL instance that is running on windows server.

Thank you.

Comment: What operating system are you running on AWS? `C:` is a Windows pathname.

Comment: I am accessing the AWS instance from my windows 11 computer

Comment: `INTO OUTFILE` writes to a file on the server, not the client.

Comment: *`secure_file_priv:  /tmp/`* means that the outfile path must be `/tmp/`.

Comment: check your database username and password. i think you pushing with wrong username and password

Answer (score 1):

You need to out file the csv file to aws instance first, and then download it to your windows computer.